# can't float images inside a div, images end up outside of main div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this page:
http://mockingbirdagency.com/thebox/tvshow.html

http://mockingbirdagency.com/thebox/style.css

I can't float the small icons at the bottom inside the main div (they somehow end up outside)... I've tried float left right but the pictures still end up outside the main .bloc div. I checked for missing closing tags but that isn't it either.
Anybody can tell me why ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with a fixed height on one of your inner divs.

```
.bottom-presentation-tv {
    float: left;
    height: 50px; /* remove this  */
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I still need to clear my floats ?